# Attributing sprite node scale to another node

Tags: objective-c, sprite, sprite-kit

How to simply attribute one spritenode scale to another node?

```
 ball.scale = block3.scale;
```

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: "No getter method for read from property"

Comment: These are `SKNode`s? Looks like you have to get the x and y scales separately.

Answer (score 2):

`SKSpriteNode` inherits the `xScale` and `yScale` properties from `SKNode`

Here is an example of what I believe you are trying to do :

```
ball.xScale = otherBall.xScale;
ball.yScale = otherBall.yScale;
```

You should take the time to go over the properties and methods of `SKNode` as all the various node types inherit from `SKNode`. Knowing what they are and what they do, will save you a great deal of time and avoid basic questions like this one.

`SKNode` in SpriteKit reference docs :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKNode